# Rewriting "pretty links" causng 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

After much research, I've finally learned that mod_rewrite does not create "pretty links", rather it rewrites them to "normal" links that get processed by the server.

With some generous help here on SO, I have been able to do some basic URL rewriting, specifically removing the `www.` and also the `.php` file extension even when a user types in `page.php`. The .htaccess code for reference:

```
RewriteEngine On

# omit www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

# To internally redirect /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This website I'm working on has a news section, the links use a query string to pass the article id from links in the sidebar like so:

`<a href="news.php?id=' . $phpVariable . '...etc.`

After finding this amazing post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained) I began experimenting with this line of code from the post:

`RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ /blog/index.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]`

and modified it to match my website like so:

`RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$ news?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Then I modified the link code in my news section to this:

`<a href="news/' . $phpVariable . '/`...etc.

so that the link would be "pretty" and be rewritten with the modified `RewriteRule` shown above.

The new `RewriteRule` was placed at the bottom of the .htaccess code (which may be part of the problem?) shown here:

```
RewriteEngine On

# omit www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

# To internally redirect /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# rewrite pretty link to fetch news article
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$ news?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now when the news section is tested, any item selected from the sidebar causes a 500 Internal Server Error.

I'm just a bit in over my head, though thanks to the information here on SO, the regex is beginning to make more and more sense to me.

Comment: I just copied the `error.log` and it oddly, it shows nothing recent (only some minor php errors from the 27th of last month). The URL causing the error is the `news` page itself, `news/1/` for example, the first article having been selected.

Comment: Do you get 500 when you directly enter `http://example.com/news/1` in browser?

Comment: Yes sir, I did. (I don't know why I didn't think to try that...thanks for the tip)

Comment: My syntax may not be completely on point. The Internal server Error page comes up with this at the bottom `Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` so I assume(d) that this was a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on question and comments I will suggest you to have it this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# omit www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# rewrite pretty link to fetch news article
RewriteRule ^news/(\d+)/?$ news.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# To internally redirect /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error but it is now missing the `Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` part. What other information can I provide to better assist?

Comment: Yes, I copied the exact code in your answer. I've downloaded the error log but am having a fit uncompressing it.

Comment: Without knowing relevant error text from `error.log` we can't solve it. On the other side I've tested this .htaccess on my Apache and everything worked fine.

Comment: Okay, I was able to access the log, here is what it said: `mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.`

Comment: Do you have this .htaccess inside a subdirectory by any chance?

Comment: No sir, it's in the site root. That error log message has me wondering...is there a way to reset the number of redirects that it mentions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137494/discussion-between-wordman-and-anubhava).

Comment: This worked perfectly, @anubhava had me add `<base href="/" />` directly below the opening `<head>` tag to get my CSS styling to affect the other pages. Works!!!